# scaling individual images into grid squares?

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm pretty new to this & I'm trying to figure out how to scale and clip these images to fit into each grid square without having a border...

I also don't know if this is an effective way to set up my images. I'd like to have a different image for each square, but how it's set up now I'd have to make a new `.box .inner#` for each one.  If there is a better way to structure this that'd be really helpful.

```css
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 240vw;
  max-width: 200vh;
  height: 240vw;
  max-height: 200vh;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.box .inner1 {
  background-image: url("https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1763/29556413048_164120ccb5_b.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(36, 36, 36), 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.box .inner2 {
  background-image: url("https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/922/43509246041_043aff0334_h.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(36, 36, 36), 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner1">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner1">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner1">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner1">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner2">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner2">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner2">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner2">8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds to me like your question is more about optimization and best practice as opposed to "how do I do X?" Is that correct?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ this might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do it like this:

```css
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 240vw;
  max-width: 200vh;
  height: 240vw;
  max-height: 200vh;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.box > div {
  background-size:cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(36, 36, 36), 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.inner1 {
background-image: url("https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1763/29556413048_164120ccb5_b.jpg");
}
.inner2 {
  background-image: url("https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/922/43509246041_043aff0334_h.jpg");
}
.inner3 {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?3");
}
.inner4 {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?4");
}
.inner5 {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300?5");
}
.inner6 {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300?6");
}
.inner7 {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/200?7");
}
.inner8 {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300?8");
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner1">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner3">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner4">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner5">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner6">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner7">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="inner8">8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh wow ok, I haven't seen `.box > div` before in css I'll have to look it up

Comment: I added `background-position: center;` to the `.box > div` and that got all the images centered up.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure if this will fix your problem but maybe take off the margin in your .box class in your css file. 
[not enough reputation yet so click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45lg9.png)

Instead of having your margin at 5px change it to 0px and see if that helps.

As for the different images you just need to create  a new class for each image an link a new image to that class, go back and link it up like you have with the two previous.